# C++ Builder Character Array Addressing

Tags: c++, character, c++builder

I'm having trouble accessing individual characters in character array in C++ Builder IDE. For some reason the quotation mark doesn't terminate the character and the code following it is considered a part of that character, at least that's what I'm getting out of it (or is it trying to tell me something else?):

[image: IDE screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` serves as an escape character, you should use `'\\'` instead to express `\`, just like you would use `'\''` to express `'`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Piotr said, you don't need to copy the string data into a separate array just to iterate through it, you can iterate through the original string directly instead.

If fileNameString is a `System::String`:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= fileNameString.Length(); ++i)
{
    if(fileNameString[i] == '\\' || fileNameString[i] == ':') {
        ...    
    }
}
```

If fileNameString is a `std::string`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileNameString.length(); ++i)
{
    if(fileNameString[i] == '\\' || fileNameString[i] == ':') {
        ...    
    }
}
```

Or:

```
for(std::string::iterator iter = fileNameString.begin(); iter != fileNameString.end(); ++iter)
{
    if(*iter == '\\' || *iter == ':') {
        ...    
    }
}
```